# Pursuing Blender

Tags: modeling, animation

Well I am a teen and For the past month I have watched other Youtubers make animations on Blender.I am from India where animation colleges don't use Blender. I have always been fascinated in how animation movies are made and 3d creations

If possible I would like your opinion on:

1. Is  Blender ideal for me?
2. Are there courses for free or for a less price where I can understand using nodes and making moving 3d models in Blender?
3. Are there colleges that teach and use Blender that are out of India?

Would Love to Have Your Opinion.
Thank You....

Comment: First off, blender is free, but can do the same work as a lot of $1000 (75,000R) software, so it's hard to go wrong. While blender isn't "industry standard" at the moment, nearly all the same modelling techniques are used, making it a very good tool to learn how to use 3D software (in general), with techniques that apply to all modeling programs.  Because blender is free, it has the largest available selection of free tutorials of all the 3D modelling softwares. Though this is just an opinion, I would say blender is a good starting choice - a good (risk free) way to learn 3D software.